# How to fetch only user ever transaction on specific payment channel in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a dataset containing user id, order id, payment channel.
I want to fetch only user who ever transaction for each payment channel

for instance,

- user A, payment channel A, B, C
- user B, payment channel B, C
- user C, payment channel A
- user D, payment channel A
- user E, payment channel B
- user F, payment channel C

The expectation is:
ever transact in payment channel A is 2
ever transact in payment channel B is 1
ever transact in payment channel C is 1

I do not want any other user who has a transaction in another payment to be included.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide sample data (I highly doubt that you actually have `payment channel A, B, C` value in one of the columns) and desired output. Also your description is quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you need to use `group by` in combination with `having`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(user, payment_channel) as
    (values ('user A', 'A'),
        ('user A', 'B'),
        ('user A', 'C'),
        ('user B', 'B'),
        ('user B', 'C'),
        ('user C', 'A'),
        ('user C', 'A'),
        ('user D', 'A'),
        ('user E', 'B'),
        ('user F', 'C')
)

-- query
select user, arbitrary(payment_channel) payment_channel
from dataset
group by user
having count(distinct payment_channel) = 1;
```

Output:

| user | payment_channel |
| --- | --- |
| user C | A |
| user E | B |
| user D | A |
| user F | C |